# What to do if you're not satisfied with an API?

Tags: python, api, oop, subclassing, urwid

I am learning urwid.

Urwid listboxes have an API that doesn't suite me. For example, in order to change focus to the next/previous element, I would like to write :

```
listbox.focus_next() / listbox.focus_previous()
```

But the API offered by urwid.ListBox is like this :

1) focus on the previous element in the listbox

```
listwalker = listbox.body
widget,current_position  = listwalker.get_focus()
try : 
    widget,previous_position = listwalker.get_prev(current_position)
    listwalker.set_focus(previous_position)
except : 
     # you're at the beginning of the listbox
     pass
```

2) focus on the next element in the listbox

```
# same code, except that you change get_prev with get_next
listwalker = listbox.body
widget,current_position  = listwalker.get_focus()
try : 
    widget,next_position = listwalker.get_next(current_position)
    listwalker.set_focus(next_position)
except : 
     # you're at the end of the listbox
     pass
```

And notice that all those methods are not called on the listbox itself but on one of its attributes (body).

Unhappy with this situation, I decided to subclass listbox itself to offer two new services (methods) to the API : focus_previous() and focus_next(), like this :

```
class MyListBox(urwid.ListBox):
    def focus_next(self):
        try: 
            self.body.set_focus(self.body.get_next(self.body.get_focus()[1])[1])
        except:
            pass
    def focus_previous(self):
        try: 
            self.body.set_focus(self.body.get_prev(self.body.get_focus()[1])[1])
        except:
            pass
```

Is this (subclassing) the right approach to take when dealing with unpleasant APIs ?

Comment: It looks nice, but you could return something from `focus_next` and `_previous`, because this way the caller doesn't know if it worked or not.

Comment: I would probably create a wrapper class rather than directly subclassing it. But perhaps that is overly cautious. This approach will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

As long as `MyListBox` is still able to stand in wherever a regular `ListBox` does, subclassing should be safe.  After all, `MyListBox` really *is* a `ListBox`, just a special one.

The [Urwid documentation](http://urwid.org/tutorial/#question-and-answer) itself seems to agree:

> Here we are customizing the Filler decoration widget that is holding our Edit widget by subclassing it and defining a new keypress() method. Customizing decoration or container widgets to handle input this way is a common pattern in Urwid applications. This pattern is easier to maintain and extend than handling all special input in an unhandled_input function.

If you find yourself having too much spare time, you might also want to read through [Composition Instead Of Inheritance](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?CompositionInsteadOfInheritance) on the original Wiki, which maybe gives too many opinions of which is best in which situation.